# Why is my database throwing an error?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to access my app through the admin site while doing the Django tutorial and am getting this error:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/polls/poll/ (1054, "Unknown column 'polls_poll.question' in 'field list'")
```

I had originally set my models to use the Question class while mistakenly using the 1.6 version of the tutorial, but switched to the 1.54 version and had to rename my Question class to Polls.  I then resynced the database.  I am using MySQL.

Now every time I click "Polls" from the admin site it throws the above error.

I have tried flushing my database and resyncing but that didn't work.

Here's my **models.py** code:

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.question

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

class Choice(models.Model):

    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Here's the full traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/polls/poll/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 372, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 202, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
    return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
    return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1285, in changelist_view
    'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 106, in __len__
    self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 317, in iterator
    for row in compiler.results_iter():
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 775, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 128, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 120, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 201, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/Users/MyClean/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'polls_poll.question' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. Also, are you sure that the column `polls_poll.question` exist?

Comment: try deleting the database and syncing again

Comment: @aIKid I just added the full traceback.

Comment: @akonsu I tried doing that with '$python manage.py flush' and then resyncing but it still doesn't work.  I am thinking about creating a fresh db from scratch and changing my settings to point to it, but feel like this is the noob solution.

Comment: this is what I am proposing as well. `flush` does not delete the database, it just removes data from it.

Comment: @akonsu  Thanks!  Fortunately the answer below solved the issue but thanks you for your input, glad to learn I had another alternative.

Comment: the answer is basically the same method. it is just that instead of all the tables you only drop the stale one. consider using django south (http://south.aeracode.org/), which can help you implement database migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's `syncdb` command will only create tables that do not already exist.  So if you've previously synced the database with a different version of the model, any changes in the field names will not be present in the database table.

To verify, use the `mysql` client to inspect your `polls_poll` table.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE polls_poll;
```

You'll probably see that the `question` field is missing.

As suggested in the comments, you can wipe your entire database, but a less invasive solution would simply be to drop the `polls_poll` table and run `syncdb` again.

```
mysql> DROP TABLE polls_poll;
$ manage.py syncdb
```

This will of course remove all data associated with polls.

Comment: Thanks!  Learned a lot from this, appreciate the help!